# Hibernate sql error1146

Tags: hibernate

I am trying simple hibernate example.But, i'm unable to create database table using hibernate.What could be the problem?
Java version1.7.Hibernate 3.6.4
My hibernate.cfg.xml is directly under src directory:

false
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        password
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
        root
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        true

```
    <mapping class="org.koushik.javabrains.dto.UserDetails"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

my main class:
public class HibernateTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
```

UserDetails user=new UserDetails();

user.setUserId(1);

```
user.setUsername("First user");

SessionFactory sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

}

This is the complete trace i get:
202 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
213 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.4.Final
215 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
220 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
227 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
331 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
331 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
466 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
549 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: org.koushik.javabrains.dto.UserDetails
618 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity org.koushik.javabrains.dto.UserDetails on table UserDetails
693 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
703 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
715 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
715 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
715 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
733 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
733 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
1197 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
1219 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.6.12-log
      major : 5
      minor : 6
1219 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Driver ->
       name : MySQL Connector Java
    version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
      major : 5
      minor : 1
1220 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
1222 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
1222 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
1222 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
1223 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
1223 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
1223 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
1223 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
1223 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
1224 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
1224 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
1225 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
1225 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
1225 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
1225 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
1228 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
1229 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
1229 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
1237 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
1238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
1238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
1238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
1238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
1238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
1270 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
1278 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@8247262
1278 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@10d1841b
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@2b38113d
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@2b38113d
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@6df3d1f5
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@225d6438
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@225d6438
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@215eaa28
1279 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@4df53935
1569 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (username, userId) values (?, ?)
1702 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
1702 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.koushik.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:25)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
    ... 11 more

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate reads and writes to tables, but doesn't create them (by default). If you want Hibernate to create your tables, then you have to set the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your config file to [one of the documented values](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties):

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto    Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

Comment: Thank you so much JB!! i had copied the config from an online resource.It did not have that field.